# Run electron-app with sudo privileges asking only once for password

Tags: node.js, electron, privileges

I'm building an electron-app where i need to run commands with superuser privileges, i don't want to ask the user for a password every time. How can i start the app, asking only for the password once. I tried:

```
sudo /path/to/electron --no-sandbox main.js
```

Unfortunately, i get this error:

[image]

I know there are libraries like https://www.npmjs.com/package/sudo-prompt, but i only want to ask once for permission.  I run everything locally, so please don't tell me about the security risk of running browser as root.

Comment: I am also struggling with sudo-prompt asking for pw every time I am seeking for test...